# Directive two way binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm relative new to AngularJS and trying to create a directive for add some buttons. I'm trying to modify the controller scope from inside the directive but I can't get it to work. Here is an example of my app

```
app.controller('invoiceManagementController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.gridViewOptions = {
        isFilterShown: false,
        isCompact: false
    };
}]);

app.directive('buttons', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<button type="button" data-button="search" title="Filter"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>',
        scope: {
            gridViewOptions: '='
        },
        transclude: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl, transclude) {
            element.find("button[data-button='search']").bind('click', function (evt) {
                // Set the property to the opposite value
                scope.gridViewOptions.isFilterShown = !scope.gridViewOptions.isFilterShown

                transclude(scope.$parent, function (clone, scope) {
                    element.append(clone);
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

My HTML like following

```
{{ gridViewOptions.isFilterShown }}
<div data-buttons="buttons" data-grid-view-options="gridViewOptions"></div>
```

The scope inside the directive does change but is like isolated, I did try paying with the scope property and transclude but I'm probably missing something, would appreciate some light here

Answer (score 0):

When you modify scope inside of your directive's link function, you are modifying your directive's isolated scope (because that is what you have set up). To modify the parent scope, you can put the scope assignment inside of your transclude function:

```
transclude(scope.$parent, function (clone, scope) {
    // Set the property to the opposite value
    scope.gridViewOptions.isFilterShown = !scope.gridViewOptions.isFilterShown
    element.append(clone);
});
```

Comment: On the html I have `{{ gridViewOptions.isFilterShown }}` I want the 2 way data binding, is that possible? I can see with you solution it does change the parent scope wich is good

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally found a solution for this after some more research today. Not sure if the best solution, but this works so good for now.

```
app.controller('invoiceManagementController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.gridViewOptions = {
        isFilterShown: false,
        isCompact: false
    };
}]);

app.directive('buttons', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<button type="button" data-button="search" data-ng-class="gridViewOptions.isFilterShown ? \'active\' : ''" title="Filter"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>',
        scope: {
            gridViewOptions: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl, transclude) {
            element.find("button[data-button='search']").bind('click', function (evt) {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    // Set the property to the opposite value
                    scope.gridViewOptions.isFilterShown = !scope.gridViewOptions.isFilterShown;
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```